# get execution time and memory usage of each plugin programatically

Tags: wordpress

I want to get each WordPress plugin execution time and memory usage by it. I have gone through WordPress documentation and google search but I am getting code regarding complete page but not specific plugin.

Following codes, I have found

```
$wpdb->queries
echo get_num_queries();
timer_stop(1);
```

Can anyone guide me how I can get execution time and memory usage for specific plugin only?

Answer (score 1):

Already exists plugin [**Debug Bar**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) and another plugin (addon for that) you will need: [**Debug Bar-Slow Actions**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar-slow-actions/).

then you will get such results:
[image]

Comment: Yes I agree there are many plugins available. I want to make my own plugin with some enhancements so need idea how they are getting each plugins execution time separately.

Answer (score 1):

Another plugin I can recommend is P3 (Plugin Performance Profiler):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/